# Best way to pass data retrivied from API between routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-services

So I am wondering what is the best way to pass data retrivied from an API endpoint to another component without requesting data again? So from what I can understand I can do this with a Service shared between the two components but when should I store data in the service? And what are the best practices in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to share data beetwen multiple components you should use a service, as you already said.

But you should not store the data inside the components.
The service should be in charge of requesting and storing the data.

Each component will request the data to the service. The service will execute the actual HTTP call or return the data from its local cache.
For this to work, ensure you have a single instance of the service (ie in app.module register it in the providers section).

Comment: Let's say the first component calls the function to get the data from the API, should the component call a function of the service to store the data, or should I do it somehow directly in the service ?

Comment: The component should call service.getData();

What the service will actually do to get the data (ie call a webservice, get them from a local array, etc) should not be a concern  for the component.

If you get the data from multiple components you have to write the data fetching code multiple times (which is bad by itself) and handle what to do when different components try to push different data to the sharing service (which can be even worse).

Answer (score 0):

Import BehaviorSubject to Service file (for eg: ApiProvider.ts)

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```

Created Required variables

```
  public  dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public dataSourceChanges$ = this.dataSource.asObservable();
```

Once Api response is received call below method .This will send data to the components who ever subscribed

```
 changeInDatatatus(data:any): void {
    this.selectedNetworkSource.next(data);
  }
```

And in the component OnInit

```
 this.dataSubscription = this.ApiProvider.dataSourceChanges$.subscribe(
      (apiData) => {
        
        if (apiData) {

        assign to your component local variable
          this.componenetLocalvar = apiData;
        }
      });
```

You can subscribe to this observable in multiple components when ever data changes data will shared across all subscribed components

Note:

Dont forget to Unsubscribe in Component OnDestroy